# Upgrade from nginx 1.22.1 to 1.24 on Amazon Linux 2 AMI

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, yum, amazon-linux-2

If possible I would like to upgrade to NGINX version 1.24 on a live ec2 instance with only minimal downtime. I followed the directions in this [post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUEWFr2r5XRWyi-XrpgTKx2w/amazon-linux2-and-nginx-version) and I’ve successfully added the nginx-stable and nginx main-line repositories.

When I run this command:

```
yum upgrade nginx-1.24.0 --disableplugin=priorities
```

I get the following error message:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /etc/logrotate.d/nginx from install of nginx-1:1.24.0-1.amzn2.ngx.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx-core-1:1.22.1-1.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/nginx from install of nginx-1:1.24.0-1.amzn2.ngx.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx-core-1:1.22.1-1.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
  file /var/log/nginx from install of nginx-1:1.24.0-1.amzn2.ngx.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx-core-1:1.22.1-1.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
  file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf from install of nginx-1:1.24.0-1.amzn2.ngx.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx-core-1:1.22.1-1.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
```

yum also attempts to update the openssl11 dependency